# List of Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to create a php page that shows, for each address contained in an array, a Google map. 
The code I wrote is wrong, what I see is a column of grey maps except the last maps, that contains a lot of markers. 
Instead, what I would like is a list of maps each with a single marker.
The array of addresses is taken from the database using php, this array is then passed to javascript using the function json_encode.

I hope this image can help you better understand what I want and what I get with my code instead [enter link description here](http://imageshack.com/a/img706/297/n5sc.png)

Code HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>

          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css"/>
          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

          <script type='text/javascript'>
             var addresses = <?php echo json_encode($addresses); ?>;
          </script>     
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/maps.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
                   <!-- mappe Google --> 
                   <div id="content_map-canvas">         
                   </div>               
        </body>
    </html>
```

Code javascript:

```
    function initialize() {
       var count = -1; //Is used to number the div (one per address)
       var descriptions = new Array(); //Array of descriptions

       //I copy the contents of the addresses array in the descriptions array 
       for(var i=0; i<addresses.length; i++) {
          var address = addresses[i];  
          var description = addresses[i];

          var geoc = "geocoder" + i;
          eval("var " + geoc);    

          var map = "map" + i;
          eval("var " + map);  

          geoc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var options = {
                 zoom: 15, 
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
              }; 

          count = count + 1;

          var id = "map-canvas" + count;
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.id = id;
          div.style.width= "300px";
          div.style.height= "300px";

          var content_map_canvas = document.getElementById("content_map-canvas");

          content_map_canvas.appendChild(div);

          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), options);

          geoc.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {   
             if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                      ({map: map, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        title: description 
                      });
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);

                contentString = description;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                  content: contentString
                }); 

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
             }
             else {
               alert("Geocode failed: " + status + ", " + address);
             }
          });    
       }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure problem. All markers are set to last map from for loop and also only the last map from the list is properly defined. You have to enclose your `geocode` part in:

```
...
(function(address, map) {
    geoc.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        console.log(address + ', status: ' + status);
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                ({map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: description 
            });
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);

            contentString = description;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            }); 

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("Geocode failed: " + status + ", " + address);
        }
    });    
})(address, map)
...
```